is this not valid spring data jpa quary List<GoodsOrder> findAllByOrderinghoomIdAndStatusIn(List<Long> roomId, Collection<OrderStatus> statuses); }
I was try to write query to retrieve values from database where it's id is in the given list of id and its status is ON-WAY,or SETTED from those?
so I did this so far :List<GoodsOrder> findAllByOrderinghoomIdAndStatusIn(List<Long> roomId, Collection<OrderStatus> statuses);
instead of getting the list I got this error
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.TravelConcierge.Hotel.Repository.BookingRepository.findAllByOrderinghoomIdAndStatusIn(java.util.List,java.util.Collection); Operator SIMPLE_PROPERTY on orderinghoom.id requires a scalar argument, found interface java.util.List in method public abstract java.util.List com.TravelConcierge.Hotel.Repository.BookingRepository.findAllByOrderinghoomIdAndStatusIn(java.util.List,java.util.Collection)


Hello and welcome! You're defining an interface method to do a query for you through JPA, and it seems that what you're willing to query is a value that can be a equals to an id and not a list of ids. Your prototype looks ready to query (Long roomId, Collection<OrderStatus> statuses) maybe, but not (List<Long> roomId, Collection<OrderStatus> statuses). What is inside GoodsOrder, by the way? Can you show us the content of this entity?
